# Mostrar valor de tags do xml nfe nas colunas do datagridview

Tags: c#

Estou com um probleminha porque estou lendo as tags de um xml de NFe, mas não estou conseguindo mostrar nas colunas do datagridview, meu código esta lendo as tags corretas, mas não aprece nada no datagridview.

segue a parte do xml que estou lendo

```
-<det nItem="1">


-<prod>

<cProd>PA3003</cProd>

<cEAN/>

<xProd>OLEO ESSENCIAL DE CITRONELA</xProd>

<NCM>33012911</NCM>

<CEST>2000600</CEST>

<EXTIPI>00</EXTIPI>

<CFOP>5101</CFOP>

<uCom>KG</uCom>

<qCom>25.0000</qCom>

<vUnCom>123.900000000</vUnCom>

<vProd>3097.50</vProd>

<cEANTrib/>

<uTrib>KG</uTrib>

<qTrib>25.0000</qTrib>

<vUnTrib>123.900000000</vUnTrib>

<indTot>1</indTot>

<xPed>002497/1</xPed>

</prod>
```

segue meu codigo

```
private void btn_xml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"C:\Xml_Entrada\2053- CITROLEO.xml";
    List<string> ListaItens = new List<string>();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FileName);
    var proditens = doc.GetElementsByTagName("prod");
    foreach (XmlElement nodo in proditens)
    {
            ListaItens.Add(nodo.GetElementsByTagName("cProd")[0].InnerText.Trim());
            ListaItens.Add(nodo.GetElementsByTagName("xProd")[0].InnerText.Trim());
            ListaItens.Add(nodo.GetElementsByTagName("qCom")[0].InnerText.Trim());
    }

    dgw_Xml.DataSource = ListaItens;

}
```

Segue o resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
class ClasseItensXml
{
    string CodigoProduto;
    string NomeProduto;
    string QtdProduto;

    public string CodigoP
    {
        get { return CodigoProduto; }
        set { CodigoProduto = value; }
    }

    public string NomeP
    {
        get { return NomeProduto; }
        set { NomeProduto = value; }
    }
    public string QtdP
    {
        get { return QtdProduto; }
        set { QtdProduto = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: você está colocando na `ListaItens` e colocando como source o `proditens`...

Comment: Então Rovann obrigado pela atenção, mas quando eu coloco a ListaItens, me aparece só uma coluna no datagridview com o tamanho das tags do xml como mostro abaixo

Comment: Você tem que editar sua pergunta, e não publicar como uma resposta. O DataGridView espera receber linhas e colunas pra exibir os dados, você tem que fornece-los nesse formato. Adicione o código da classe que você quer exibir (imagino que seja `ListaItens`) que podemos demonstrar como fazer.

Comment: Se puder me mostrar como fazer agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro vamos alterar sua classe, apenas por questão estética:

```
public class ClasseItensXml
{
    public string CodigoProduto {get;set;}
    public string NomeProduto {get;set;}
    public string QuantidadeComercializada {get;set;}
}
```

Depois o código, aqui basta você alterar a lista para o tipo dos itens, e depois usa-la como source:

```
private void btn_xml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"C:\Xml_Entrada\2053- CITROLEO.xml";
    List<ClasseItensXml> ListaItens = new List<ClasseItensXml>(); //A lista é do tipo ClasseItensXml
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FileName);
    var proditens = doc.GetElementsByTagName("prod");

    foreach (XmlElement nodo in proditens)
    {
            ListaItens.Add(
                 new ClasseItensXml()
                 { 
                      CodigoProduto = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("cProd")[0].InnerText.Trim(),
                      NomeProduto = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("xProd")[0].InnerText.Trim(),
                      QuantidadeComercializada = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("qCom")[0].InnerText.Trim()
                 });

            //Repare que cada "nodo" é um item, portanto só adiciona um ClasseItensXml na lista.
    }

    dgw_Xml.DataSource = ListaItens; //por fim, usa a lista de source

}
```

ps. Eu utilizaria decimal na quantidade, mas pra simplificar a resposta não alterei isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rovann deu certinho aqui vlw.

Comment: Rovann pode me tirar uma duvida, estou tenatndo transformar a QuantidadeComercializada de string para Decimal, só que o resultado na coluna no datagrid, fica errado, por ex. tenho 360.000 quando transformo para decimal a coluna o numero fica 3.600.000,00, como posso resolver isso. Pode me ajudar.

Comment: cadê o código que está usando pra conversão ?!

Comment: veja esse código: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DN2P8m

Comment: Então Rovann, preciso criar uma função para fazer a conversão antes, porque o que estou fazendo, era só mudando na classe a coluna de string para decimal, achando que já resolveria o problema.Pegando public string QuantidadeComercializada {get;set;} e mudando para public decimal QuantidadeComercializada {get;set;}.

Comment: aí você vai ter que converter a string que vem do xml...

Comment: Rovann, esta formula de exemplo que vc me enviou, esta certinho depois que eu converto o meu xml retorna da forma que esta no exemplo que vc me enviou, o problema e que estou fazendo uma divisão usando este valor. Ex o retorno do xml em decimal esta me mostrando desta forma 3600000 só que este valor e quantidade o certo seria aparecer somente 360 que e a quantidade do item no xml. Da forma que esta aparecendo 3600000 quando faço a divisão por 2 o resultado e de 1.800.000,00, que deviria ser de 180.